# check if atleast 4 consecutive array elements are same — javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hello i have to check Arrays(all have equal lengths) which have same elements(null in mycase) in atleast 4 consecutive positions. and return true if it has so.

Example,

```
Arr1 = ["a","","b","c","","","","","d"]; // if array is like this it should return - True
Arr1 = ["","","","","","a","b","c","d"]; // if it is like this it should return - True
Arr1 = ["p","q","","r","","","s","",""]; // if it is like this it should return - False
```

Any idea?? Please Help advise or suggest somecode in the below function so to acheive this requirement in javascript

```
function checkForSameConsecutives(arr) {

 //somecode here 

 // if condition to return true/false;
};
checkForSameConsecutives(Arr1);
```

Comment: what is the specific problem, you are facing?

Comment: *Any* code would be a good start... Otherwise you should be looking to hire a dev.

Comment: how is posting this question not easier than just writing that function? don't get it

Comment: why is the third example false?

Comment: Because it does not have "atleast 4 consecutive positions"

Comment: @NinaScholz third example do not have 4 nulls together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a closure over a counter `c` and check the value and reset if the value is truthy or add one. Then return the result of the check with the wanted length.

```js
const check = array => (c => array.some(v => (c = v ? 0 : c + 1) === 4))(0);

console.log(check(["a", "", "b", "c", "", "", "", "", "d"]));
console.log(check(["", "", "", "", "", "a", "b", "c", "d"]));
console.log(check(["p", "q", "", "r", "", "", "s", "", ""]));
```

Comment: Wow, I admire your answer!

Comment: Simply brilliant. Never thought it can be done this way.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
function checkForSameConsecutives(haystack, needle, howMany) {
  let counter = 0;
  for (const el of haystack) {
    if (el === needle) {
      counter++;
      if (counter === howMany) {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Arguments to the function:

`haystack` - the array to search

`needle`  - what are you searching for

`howMany` - how many hits do you need

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr1 = ["a", "", "b", "c", "", "", "", "", "d"]; // if array is like this it should return - True
arr2 = ["", "", "", "", "", "a", "b", "c", "d"]; // if it is like this it should return - True
arr3 = ["p", "q", "", "r", "", "", "s", "", ""];

function hasFourOrMoreConsecutiveElements(arr) {
  let hasFourOrMoreConsecutiveElements = false;
  arr
    .join("-") // Replace "" with '-' and convert into string
    .split(/[a-zA-Z]/) // split on alphabetical characters into separate arrays -> will look like ["---", "--", "----", ...]
    .forEach((array) => { // iterate over arrays
      if (array.length >= 4) { // check if any subarray has 4 or more items
        hasFourOrMoreConsecutiveElements= true;
        return;
      }
    });
  return hasFourOrMoreConsecutiveElements;
}

console.log(
  hasFourOrMoreConsecutiveElements(arr1),
  hasFourOrMoreConsecutiveElements(arr2),
  hasFourOrMoreConsecutiveElements(arr3)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
Arr1 = ["a","","b","c","","","","","d"]; // if array is like this it should return - True
Arr2 = ["","","","","","a","b","c","d"]; // if it is like this it should return - True
Arr3 = ["p","q","","r","","","s","",""]; // if it is like this 
function checkForSameConsecutives(arr) {
  for(let i=0; i < arr.length - 3; i+=1){
    const ArrayToCheck = arr.slice(i, i+4)
    const ArrayToCheckSet = new Set(ArrayToCheck)
    if(ArrayToCheckSet.size === 1){
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
};

console.log(checkForSameConsecutives(Arr1))
console.log(checkForSameConsecutives(Arr2))
console.log(checkForSameConsecutives(Arr3))
```

This is not most optimised. But might give you some direction. Here code is iterating on every index and checking if next three elements are same.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this following simple code help you

```
function checkForSameConsecutives(arr) {
            var count = 0;
            var isFound = false;
            for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
                    count++;
                    if (count == 3) {
                        isFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return isFound;
        }
```

This is not be the best solution but it may help you to start.